# How to set alarm in iphone calendar application from the our application?

Tags: iphone

I have implemented event calendar application.In which I have added event data in iphone calendar application from my application successfully.But I also want to add alarm from my application.Please give me some idea about that.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
EKEvent *event  = [EKEvent eventWithEventStore:eventStore];
EKAlarm *alarm = [EKAlarm alarmWithRelativeOffset:alarmOffset];
[event addAlarm:alarm];
```